# Wikipedia API: Only returns 10 pageids

Tags: http, wikipedia, url-parameters

I have the following HTTP POST which should return all Marvel superheroes (200 pages). However, it only returns 10.

```
  http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&format=json&list=categorymembers&cmtitle=Category:Marvel_Comics_superheroes
```

What parameter is missing? Documentation was not much of a help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [cmlimit](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Categorymembers) param, it looks like it defaults to 10.

The examples towards the bottom that page are especially useful.

Comment: Thanks! Solved my problem instantly.